# How to build a circuit for torque control using a DC motor, current sensor and arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, torque

I have been tasked with designing a circuit that controls the output torque of a DC motor. The requirements are that the motor should operate at one of two torque values (inputted using a toggle switch). This should be done using an arduino uno as well as a DiodeZetex 5 pin current sensor. I am unsure of how to actually fit all of the components together - specifically, I am not sure how to use the current sensor or how to 'set' the current of the motor?

Comment: "all of the components" lacks the motor driver at which you might be able to control the current, corresponding to the torque.

Comment: Torque and speed are related, so PWM speed control affects torque as well

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about circuit design, not programming.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you are using a DC motor with permanent magnets. In the datasheet there should be a torque constant *km (Nm/A)*. The torque *M* can then be calculated "ideally" with the formula *M = km * I*. The rest should be solvable with ohm's law and maybe some try and error.